# Calling classes on the heap (null string error) C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, heap-memory

I have a project for class where I'm taking a lovely list of 50 students, placing them on the heap, and then printing them, sorting, reprinting.
I have to use OOP for this, which isn't a huge deal, but I'm struggling with connecting my base data classes to their parent class.
I had it where the code was compiling, but giving me a logic_error for a null string. No clue why. Started taking out any null classes, and now it's crying foul at me again.
The code I'm working with is a bit huge, so I'm going to put in one of the working data classes, and then the class I'm trying to get to use the others and the main file, so bear with me here...

-data class, works as intended

```
.h
class Academics
{
    private:
        string GPA;
        string credits;
    public:
        Academics();
        Academics(string GPA, string credits);
        string getAcademics();
};

.cpp begins
Academics::Academics()
{
    Academics::GPA = "";
    Academics::credits = "";
}
Academics::Academics(string GPA, string credits)
{
    Academics::GPA = GPA;
    Academics::credits = credits;
}
string Academics::getAcademics()
{
    stringstream ssAcad;
    ssAcad << GPA << endl << credits << endl;
    return ssAcad.str();
}
```

-caller class, not working

```
.h
class Student
{
    private:
        Name name;
        Address address;
        Academics academics;
        Date dob;
        Date doc;
    public:
        Student();
        Student(Name name, Address address, Date dob,
                Date doc, Academics academics);
        string getStudent();
};

.cpp begins
Student::Student()
{
    Student::name = Name("Oscar", "Grouch");
    Student::address = Address("123 Sesame Street","Trash Can","New York","NY","10128");
    Student::academics = Academics("4.00", "120");
    Student::doc = Date("05","21","1993");
    Student::dob = Date("06","01","1969");
}
Student::Student(Name name, Address address, Date dob, Date doc, Academics academics)
{
    Student::name = name;
    Student::address = address;
    Student::dob = dob;
    Student::doc = doc;
    Student::academics = academics;
}
string Student::getStudent()
{
    name.getName();
    address.getAddress();
    dob.getDate();
    doc.getDate();
    academics.getAcademics();
}
```

-main

```
int main ()
{
Student student = Student();
cout << student.getStudent() << endl;
return(0);
}
```

thanks so much for any help or insight as to where I need to look

Comment: Is the first code block supposed to be two different files? (Academics.h and Academics.cpp_

Comment: Instead of dumping all your code, try to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody wants to trawl through pages and pages of stuff. If some part is "working as intended" it doesn't need to be included, take it out (and make sure the remainder still compiles, runs, and gives the error)

Comment: yes, the Academics.h and Academics.cpp are both together, as are the Students.h and Students.cpp. I figured it would be easier to block them together, but can change that if you want.

And I didn't dump all of it...I did minimize what I could. I could edit out the includes and such, but that's about it. any less and everything breaks. There's another 300ish lines not shown...

Comment: Also try debugging your code. Then you can see where the logic error comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `Student::getString()` doesn't have a return statement but is declared to return a string.

Try adding `return name.getName();` or something similar to get started with debugging.

Comment: It's always the little things that I miss and make me spend hours beating my head against a wall...no more null errors now that I'm returning values as opposed to making the computer sit and think...